# Why does Teams Admin center Meetings & Calls logs not have the complete caller ID, that is displayed for the user at time of call?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Am I missing a setting somewhere to store the full number clearly available when the log was created. Or is there another place to strangely go to view the full number alongside similar other details?

[image]